# Cannot install lubuntu-desktop

Tags: apt, lubuntu, gdebi

I am trying to install the lubuntu-desktop package.

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

fails with this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
lubuntu-desktop : Depends: gdebi but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

so I proceed with

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

leading to

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
gdebi : Depends: gdebi-core (= 0.9.5.3ubuntu2) but 0.9.5.3ubuntu1 is to be installed
Recommends: libgtk2-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I go ahead and grab this libgtk2--perl package, and then try installing gdebi again, leading to:

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt-get install gdebi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
gdebi : Depends: gdebi-core (= 0.9.5.3ubuntu2) but 0.9.5.3ubuntu1 is to be installed    
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What has gone wrong but mainly, how do I correct this??

EDIT: adding requested information

GDEBI

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt-cache policy gdebi
gdebi:
     Installed: (none)
     Candidate: 0.9.5.3ubuntu2
     Version table:
     0.9.5.3ubuntu2 0
               500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed/universe                          amd64 Packages
     0.9.5.3ubuntu1 0
               500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     0.9.5.3 0
              500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

GDEBI-CORE

```
user@host:~$ sudo apt-cache policy gdebi-core
gdebi-core:
       Installed: 0.9.5.3ubuntu1
       Candidate: 0.9.5.3ubuntu1
       Version table:
       *** 0.9.5.3ubuntu1 0
            500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
       0.9.5.3 0
            500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Can you do `apt-cache policy gdebi` and `apt-cache policy gdebi-core`? [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/465945/edit) your question and paste the output there. I'm assuming you're on Trusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a full system update and try again:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me too. I didn't try enedil's solution, but I did try `sudo apt install lubuntu-core` and *then* `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop`. I know this problem is already resolved but I thought this could be another solution.